# Обрезание строки

Tags: php, строки

Имеется строка вида

```
CN=Б*а О*а П*а,OU=Users,DC=ru
```

Необходимо оставить только `OU=Users,DC=ru`. То есть то, что после первой запятой.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$start_str = "CN=Ба Оа П*а,OU=Users,DC=ru";
$arr = explode(',', $start_str);
$end_str = join(',', array_slice($arr, 1));
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$retval = substr($str, strpos($str, ',')+1);
```